# converting year to year-month-day python pandas csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

Please I have close to 10 entries in a csv file as follow

```
PatienceID      Case        Treatment     Admitted_Date      Discharged_Date
PAT1002         Fever        Yes           1929-02-10         1929-02-13
PAT1023         Ebola        Yes           2015-10-21         2015-12-29
PAT1003         HIV          No            2012               2014-02-21
PAT1991         Headache     Yes           2013               2013
PAT2028         Epilepsy     Yes           2011               2016
PAT2931         Malaria      Yes           2016-01-23         2016
```

Please if we study the csv, there are values under `Admitted_Date` and/or `Discharged_Date` which only have a year without **Month-Day**. I don't know how to complete date with Month-DAY (I.e so that `Discharge_Date` will precede the admitted e.g. let's consider `Admitted_Date = 2013` and `Discharged_Date = 2013`, if `Admitted_Date` has `01-01-2013` then the `Discharged_Date` should have `12-12-2013` (January to December)

I have tried out possibilities but it gets messier. I appreciate, thank so much.

**Expected output:**

```
PatienceID      Case        Treatment     Admitted_Date      Discharged_Date
    PAT1002         Fever        Yes        1929-02-10         1929-02-13
    PAT1023         Ebola        Yes        2015-10-21         2015-12-29
    PAT1003         HIV          No         2012-MM-DD       2014-02-21
    PAT1991         Headache     Yes        2013-MM-DD         2013-MM-DD
    PAT2028         Epilepsy     Yes        2011-MM-DD         2016-MM-DD
    PAT2931         Malaria      Yes        2016-01-23         2016-MM-DD
```

**What I have tried so far**

```
import pandas as pd

DF = pd.read_csv('mydata.csv') 
for Admitted_Date, Discharged_Date in DF
  pd.to_datetime(mydata.pop('Date'), format="%b%Y")
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: import pandas as pd

DF = pd.read_csv('mydata.csv') 
for Admitted_Date, Discharged_Date in DF
  pd.to_datetime(mydata.pop('Date'), format="%b%Y")

Comment: Please add your code to your answer. After pasting it, select it and press Ctrl+K to indent it.

Comment: I have done.. I have edited the question with the code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can try first convert columns [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then use [`YearEnd`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects), where length of original column is `4` by `mask` and [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df['Admitted_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Admitted_Date'])
mask = df['Discharged_Date'].str.len() == 4
print mask
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
Name: Discharged_Date, dtype: bool

df['Discharged_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Discharged_Date'])
df.loc[mask, 'Discharged_Date' ] +=  pd.offsets.YearEnd()
print df
  PatienceID      Case Treatment Admitted_Date Discharged_Date
0    PAT1002     Fever       Yes    1929-02-10      1929-02-13
1    PAT1023     Ebola       Yes    2015-10-21      2015-12-29
2    PAT1003       HIV        No    2012-01-01      2014-02-21
3    PAT1991  Headache       Yes    2013-01-01      2013-12-31
4    PAT2028  Epilepsy       Yes    2011-01-01      2016-12-31
5    PAT2931   Malaria       Yes    2016-01-23      2016-12-31
```

Comment: Please is it possible to create new date from available date range e.g in a situation when there is no single date (i.e. No year is provided)? Consider PAT1991 and Admitted_Date and Discharged_Date not given and one want to use similar cases to judge estimated dates

Comment: If there is no value, how is it estimated? Replace with minimal and maximal `date`?

Comment: Sorry, Payne, but I think it is more complicated. Can you post new question? Please dont forget `sample`, desired `output` (with `dates`) and what do you try. Thanks.